# Error while sending a file in wifip2pmanager - Android Java

Tags: android, sockets, cordova-plugins

Getting below error while sending files from one device to another by using android wifip2pmanger. The device is not connecting with the other device. I didn't get any popup or alert in the other device to allow the connection. But the error says the connection was `CONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`.

```
2021-11-07 22:05:47.630 27015-27221/com.app.transfer W/System.err: OkSocket, Socket server 192.168.49.1:3876 connect failed! error msg:failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 3876) from /192.168.49.181 (port 49326) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.632 27015-27015/com.app.transfer E/WifiSocketClient: 连接失败(Connecting Failed)java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 3876) from /192.168.49.181 (port 49326) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.633 27015-27015/com.app.transfer E/WifiSocketClient: 异常信息为：com.xuhao.didi.socket.client.impl.exceptions.UnConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 3876) from /192.168.49.181 (port 49326) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.635 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err: com.xuhao.didi.socket.client.impl.exceptions.UnConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 3876) from /192.168.49.181 (port 49326) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.635 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at com.xuhao.didi.socket.client.impl.client.ConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:198)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.638 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 3876) from /192.168.49.181 (port 49326) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.638 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:273)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.638 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.638 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.639 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.639 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.639 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.639 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.640 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.641 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.641 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at com.xuhao.didi.socket.client.impl.client.ConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:188)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.642 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.642 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:262)
2021-11-07 22:05:47.642 27015-27015/com.app.transfer W/System.err:   ... 9 more
```

Comment: You are not sending files. You can only send a file if you have a connection which you have not.

Comment: I am sending a single file but I am using the loop to send multiple files.

Comment: Repeat: you are not yet sending anything as you have no connection.

Comment: Understood. Is there any solution to connect with the other device?

Comment: Tell more about the devices. And client/server.

Comment: I am sending the files from Asus Zenfone 3(Android 8) to Redmi Note 9 Pro(Android 10).

Comment: No, at the moment you try to send a file but your app should first connect with an app on the other fone. You did tell nothing about that app.